# 207 classes ( many with one object) , Movie

Tags: python, tensorflow, scikit-learn, cross-validation

```
Xtrain, Xtest, ytrain, ytest = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=1/3, random_state=85)
models = [
    RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100, max_depth=5, random_state=42),
    LinearSVC(),
    MultinomialNB(),
    LogisticRegression(random_state=0),
]

# 5 Cross-validation
CV = 5
cv_df = pd.DataFrame(index=range(CV * len(models)))

entries = []
for model in models:
  model_name = model.__class__.__name__
  accuracies = cross_val_score(model, features, labels, scoring='accuracy', cv=CV)
  for fold_idx, accuracy in enumerate(accuracies):
    entries.append((model_name, fold_idx, accuracy))
    
cv_df = pd.DataFrame(entries, columns=['model_name', 'fold_idx', 'accuracy'])
```

error :

UserWarning: The least populated class in y has only 1 members, which is less than n_splits=5.

Comment: Please reduce and enhance this into the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  Your posted code fails on the first line.

Comment: Please update the title of the question. This is not quora.

Comment: Thanks, Prune & Akshay  Iam just learning the ropes here , will try to see and absorb how people post here .

Answer (score 0):

When using cross validation, it splits the whole train set such that the train and test (in cv) will have same distribution. If there are 10 objects with label "A", which are about 20% of whole examples, it will split it to groups where every group has 2 objects with label "A" so it will also 20% from test.

But what happens when a label "A" has only 1 object (one row with that class) and you try to split it for 5 groups? This is an error you get. It does not know how to handle that.

It's a bit hard to tell how to solve it without knowing what your data looks like and what are your needs. Different problems may have different solutions.

You can:

1. Remove problematic label from dataset. Check for all classes with extreme low frequency and group them all together to "Other" or something like that.
2. Give up on cv and use `KFolds`, which does not require that groups within cv will have same distribution.

Comment: Hi, thanks , I have 207 classes of movie genres ( [act adv sport] [sport comedy drama] ..)as you correctly guessed , the last 100 or so have only 1 object . how to group /use kfolds , novice ,thanks again

Comment: Give example of your dataset. It will be easier to help you that way

Comment: Title Genre Description Director 
Guardians of the Galaxy Action,Adventure,Sci-Fi A group of intergalactic criminals are forced to work together to stop a fanatical warrior from taking control of the universe. James Gunn